# "Host '192.XXX.XXX.X' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" error when attempting to access mysql Docker container from another container

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file which creates one container to run my app (Ruby on Rails) and another to run a mysql server.

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  test-db:
    external: false

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_development
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: foobar
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: foobar
    volumes:
      - test-db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  app:
    build:
      ./
    image: test_app:latest
    env_file: .env
    command: "rails server -b 0.0.0.0"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

I exec into the db container, and can access the mysql cli as expected.

```
$ docker exec -it test_db_1 mysql -pfoobar
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

However, I am met with the following when I attempt to access the server through the app container.

```
 $ docker exec -it test_app_1 mysql -hdb -pfoobar
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.144.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Why is the container running the mysql server unable to receive requests from the test app container?

When I run `docker ps`, I see the following:

```
 COMMAND                      PORTS                            
 "rails server -b 0.0…"       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp           
 "docker-entrypoint.s…"       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

Comment: Unless your yml is broken this doesn't seem to have much to do with rails but rather with the database server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

By default when you start MySQL container, it creates automatically the root user which you are using it to access the same container `test_db_1` based on environment variables passed, this root user is granted/allowed to connect from localhost only.

But if you want to access MySQL from the other container, you should create a user that is granted to connect to the database from a remote host (either `username@%` or `username@container-name`) - as each container has a different IP inside the docker default network,

**Note**: you can do that by logging into MySQL in the container, and [create a user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html), in your case it will be something like: `` grant all on <your-database>@`%` to <yourusername>@`%` identified by '<password>' ``

Answer (score 0):

`ports`option expose the ports to your host machine but I don't think it does between the same between containers. Try using `expose: 3306` on the db configuration. By the way, I'd like to point out that even though you are using `depends_on` option that doesn't guarantee your database will be up when you start your application only that the db container will be ready so keep that in mind.